# Scala's generics

Tags: scala

I want to write a function for process sequence, like this:

```
def wrap[A >: Seq[_], B](seq : A)(f : () => B): Option[B] = {
    if(seq.isEmpty) None
    else Some(f())
}
```

But it doesn't work
error:

```
error: value isEmpty is not a member of type parameter A
```

if(seq.isEmpty) None

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to say anything about `A` at all.  Just say that the first argument to `wrap` is a `Seq`, then you can pass in a `Seq` or any subclass thereof:

```
def wrap[B](seq : Seq[_])(f : () => B): Option[B] = {
    if(seq.isEmpty) None
    else Some(f())
}

wrap(List(1,2,3))(() => "hi") //returns Some("hi")
```

Comment: Or just `seq.headOption.map(x => f())`

Answer (score 4):

What you did wrong is `>:`, you need `<:`

`A <: B` means the type `A` is less than the type `B`, in that if you think of the type as the set of all values belonging to it, type `A` is included in type `B`. This is java `A extends B`. `>:` is java `A super B`.

It is of course natural to think that `A` is greater than `B`, in that instances of `A` offer at least as many services/guarantees as instances of `B` do. But the usual notation (not only in scala) of subtyping is for inclusion.

That being said, @dhg answer is correct in that you do not need the generic parameter for this particular problem.